# slf4j and log4j configuration not working

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, jboss-logging

I can't get my configurations for logging with slf4j to work..
The error log looks like this

`INFO:   visiting unvisited references
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)] whereas object of type
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)].
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.Appender" was loaded by
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)] whereas object of type
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender" was loaded by [WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)].
SEVERE:   log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "file".
SEVERE:   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version).
SEVERE:   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
INFO:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
WARNING:   JSF1022: [true/false] Invalid value 'javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING' for configuration option 'true|false'.  Valid values are 'true|false'.  Falling back to the default of 'true'.
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/AnchorFused4.03'
INFO:   Monitoring jndi:/server/.../WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications`

I've setup the following dependencies

```
 <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also have hibernate and spring dependencies
 I have excluded commons-logging from the dependencies to avert any conflicts....

The log4j property file is place in src/main/resources and it is under WEB-INF/classes/ classpath.

```
#Log to Console as STDOUT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
#Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n

#Root Logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

I have tried several combinations with slf4j-log4j12 and slf4j-simple using each independently but both yield the same error.

Note: I have noticed that if I exclude jboss-logging from maven dependacy I do not get the Log4j Error..but unfortunately jboss-logging is a hibernate-core dependacy and application cannot run without it.